# Search within HTML code?

Tags: jquery

How do I search within HTML code with JQuery? I want to find a string in the HTML code and then hide the div. This does not work:

```
<div class="example">
test
<img src="example.jpg"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".example:contains('example.jpg')").hide();
});
```

But when I tell it to search for 'test' instead of 'example.jpg', it does work?

Comment: :contains searches text content, not content of attributes in child elements.

Comment: Is there a selector for HTML content then? I have tried .attr() and that does not work.

Comment: `$('[src="example.jpg"]')` will do it

Comment: @user2338015 No, but there is a selector for selecting elements with a specific attribute, and another for selecting elements that have descendants that match a specific selector. `$('.example:has([src="example.jpg"])').hide();`

Answer (score 2):

Combine the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and the [attribute-equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selectors.

```
$('.example:has([src="example.jpg"])').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9bgt/

this would be more efficient, due to the fact that `:has` is a custom selector implemented by jQuery:

```
$('.example').filter(':has([src="example.jpg"])').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src="example.jpg"]').parent().hide();
```

But this is very tightly coupled code, you should really design your markup better in order to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.example').html().indexOf('example.jpg')!=-1){
$('.example').hide();
}
});
```

Comment: For the benefit of future users you might consider explaining _why_.